# Gray out part of image

Tags: css

I have an image which covers an entire element using something like `#myDiv {background-image: url("../images/background.jpg "); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center;}`

Next, I would like to gray out the left side of the image similar to that shown below.

How can this be accomplished?  It doesn't need to look exactly the same, but only similar.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not just add a simple div over the top with a semi-transparent grey colour? Your examples have a semi-transparent white colour over the top.

Comment: @user3791372  How is this different than the other answers?

Comment: ... Because 1/ It's a comment not an answer, 2/ it's a concept not spoonfeeding you code 3/ it **makes you think** how to do something, and 4/ it's a basic idea so is something you can google yourself if you can't knock it up already.

Comment: @user3791372  Not asking to be spoon fed, and agree it is good to think!  So, you like something like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaaWMB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could play with a pseudoelement and a `RGBA` background, e.g.

```
#mydiv {
   background: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/cherry-wood.jpg); 
   width: 250px;
   height: 400px;
   position: relative;
}

#mydiv:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;  
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 30%;
   background: rgba(255,255,255, .3);
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyVYwe

---

Or you could simply add a transparent left border to the element, e.g.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
background-origin: border-box;
border-left: 50px rgba(255,255,255, .3) solid;
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbGNqL

---

Or you could use an inset `box-shadow`

```
box-shadow: 80px 0 0 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) inset;
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avOrXE

Comment: Interesting use of a border.  Never even thought of doing so.  Why do both approaches not provide the same color?

Comment: it was due to a `background-origin: border-box;` missing :) now they have the same transparency

Answer (score 3):

You may use linear-gradients since you use `background-image`

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 60px, transparent 60px), /* the gray, reset opacity to your needs : here 0.75 */
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 60px, red 60px, red 64px, transparent 64px), /* a red line ? */
    url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/fashion) /* and finally, image laying underneath gradients */;
  background-size: 
    auto, 
    auto, 
    auto 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not vote for this answer as it was user3791372's comment (yet not yet an answer) and not mine.  If you think it is the right approach, please provide a comment why you think so.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaaWMB

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>

#mydiv {
  background: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/cherry-wood.jpg) bottom;
  width: 230px;
  height: 400px;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nice, clean, simple, non-hacky, quick to implement, easy to read in a year's time and understand what it does. The rest is semantics. The OCD web development gang will say that semantically, if #sidebar is not to have any content, then presentation divs shouldn't be in your HTML markup, but I think the above reasons outweigh their argument and make your life easier. It's about being realistic rather than anally retentive.

Comment: @user3791372  I kind of like this answer, but would feel like a jerk if I selected it.  By the way, I never mentioned it, but #sidebar actually will have some content.

Comment: @user3791372  Also, never previously mentioned, but need #sidebar to have a right border which isn't transparent.  As such, don't think this will work unless I add another `div` to the right of #sidebar which acts as a border, and will need to use one of the other posted answers.

Comment: Could use a semi-transparent png as the background for the sidebar div which just has a border-right, or use an rgba with opacity as background - I think that may allow for an opaque border colour. Don't use filter as you don't need it nowadays

Comment: @user3791372  Thanks.  Ended up using rgba and it works perfect.